# Schedule workflow to run at every 7 PM in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm new to Dynamics CRM.

I want to send email to the client everyday at 7 PM. Also I want to create report in the email, showing sum of value of records created on current date.

1. What we need to do for daily schedule, WF or Task? How to schedule?
2. How can I get the condition to find the records created on current date and sum the value field of all the records?

Comment: We always make a Console Application + Scheduled Task for recurring activities: no need to struggle with CRM quirks *plus* log files on disk

Comment: Is this online or on-premised w/ internet access? If so, you should look at a scheduled Azure WebJob to handle this task.

Comment: Check out North52's [Scheduler](http://www.north52.com/business-process-activities/scheduler-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-xrm/). I'm pretty sure they have a trial version that you could setup and then investigate to see how they implement scheduling. I'm guessing they have one main process (workflow) that implements a wait loop and periodically looks for queued "jobs" ("job": custom entity record that describes a piece of work to perform).

Answer (score 0):

Console application + Task scheduler is the combo we use for sending reminders/report summary.

Console app will do all the business logic/record filtering using QueryExpression or FetchXML & CRM Email Activity can be created to send out. Windows Task Scheduler can be configured to run on desired window.

If you designed the workflow already, you can still use the QE to filter records & call [ExecuteWorkflowRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.executeworkflowrequest.aspx) message to invoke from Console app.